# Sum values of an array based on other value

Tags: php, arrays

Well, I have this array $city :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => paris
            [2] => FR-J
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 116729
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => marseille
            [2] => FR-U
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 12898
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => lyon
            [2] => FR-V
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 8608
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => fr
            [1] => nice
            [2] => FR-U
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 6838
            [5] => 0
            [6] => 0
        )
```

And so on ... And I would like to sum of the $city[$key][4] and would generate something like this:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FR-J
            [1] => 116729

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FR-U
            [1] => 19736
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => FR-V
            [1] => 8608
        )
```

Here's what how I try to do so :

```
$totals = array();
    foreach ($city as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($city[$key][3])){
            $totals[$key][0] = $city[$key][2];
            $totals[$key][1] += (int) $city[$key][4]; \\ <-- this line
        } else {
            $totals[$key][0] = $city[$key][2];
            $totals[$key][1] = (int) $city[$key][4];
        }
    }
```

But instead it generate this the array but with sums and `Undefined offset: 1` at the line commented. Any way I can do this ? Much appreciated.

Comment: change the marked line with this: if(!isset($totals[$key][1])) $totals[$key][1] = 0;
$totals[$key][1] += (int) $city[$key][4];

Comment: `$city[$key][4];` should be `$city[$key][3];` because array index starts from `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sum = [];

foreach($city as $value) {
    if(!isset($sum[$value[2]]))
        $sum[$value[2]] = 0;

    $sum[$value[2]] += $value[4];
}

$results = [];

foreach($sum as $key => $value)
    $results[] = [$key,$value];

print_r($results);
```

Comment: Sorry It doesn't quite work ! Can you provide a codepad or online tester ?

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you set it first, initialize it by zero. So that you wont have undefined index errors. Consider this example:

```
$new_values = array();
foreach($original_values as $key => $value) {
    if(!isset($new_values[$value[2]][1])) $new_values[$value[2]][1] = 0;
    $new_values[$value[2]][0] = $value[2];
    $new_values[$value[2]][1] += $value[4];
}

$new_values = array_values($new_values);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem.

```
$new_values = array();
foreach($original_values as $key => $value) {
      if(false == isset($new_values[$value[2]][1])) {
             $new_values[$value[2]][1] = 0;
       }

      $new_values[$value[2]][0] = $value[2];
      $new_values[$value[2]][1] += $value[4];
}
```

$new_values = array_values($new_values);

Also use bracers in if statement, it is best practice in our community.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$totals = array();
foreach ($city as $key => $value) {
    $totals[$key][0] = $city[$key][2];
    if(!isset($totals[$key][1])) 
        $totals[$key][1] = 0;
    $totals[$key][1] += (int) $city[$key][4]; 
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Udefined offset 1 means that your $total array has not element with [$key][1]. You're trying to add the number to element that does not exists. So in my example I create this element and initiate with 0 in case if it does not exists.